# How do get data of ajax call beforeSend in same ajax Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there way to get data prepared in `ajax call` before call to made.

```
 var prevData = [];
 $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            data :{"dataId":dataId, "sortedOrder":Order},
            url : "main-section/getData",
            beforeSend: function( event, xhr, settings ) {
               // Have to check data here.
                if (xhr.data==prevData ){
                  prevData =xhr.data;
                  event.abort();
                }

            },
            success : function(response) {
                // some code.
            },
            error : function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError) {
                    console.log("error occured  : "+ thrownError)
            }
            });
```

i want to comapare data in `beforesend`method of ajax.In such a way that if there is multiple calls then abort calls in waiting.

Comment: Well, what is the problem here ? Also, your title is very wrong.

Comment: thax Seblor it was by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's a problem in the javascript `event` loop?

I would suggest refactoring your code to check the data and only send the ajax request if success occurs, outside of the ajax itself. Here is the sample pseudo-code

```
example = function(prevData, ajaxCall){ 
//check prevData here
if (success) { 
ajaxCall(); 
    }
}
```